# jQuery scrollTop detection takes very long

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

So here is what I am trying to do:

I want a landing page with a fixed header. If the user scrolls down the page y px, I want to resize the header to x px. If the user scrolls up again and scrolls over the "line", it should resize to the original dimensions again. Here is my code:

```js
    $(document).scroll(function(){
        if($(document).scrollTop() > 300) {
            $("#header").animate({height: "50px"}, 400);
        }
        else {
            $("#header").animate({height: "200px"}, 400);
        }
        console.log($(document).scrollTop());
    });
```

```css
        #header {
            background-color: coral;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-around;
            height: 200px;
            align-items: center;
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: 1337;
        }
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<div id="header">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
    <a href="#">Link 5</a>
</div>

<div class="white-space">
    <h2>Some Content</h2>
</div>


    <div class="image">
        <img src="img/rsz_hnck8766.jpg">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>

<div class="white-space">
    <h2>Some Content</h2>
</div>

<div class="image">
    <img src="img/2.jpg">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>

<div class="white-space">
    <h2>Some Content</h2>
</div>


</body>

<script src="includes/jquery-2.1.4.js"> </script>

</html>
```

Now, my code does work to make the header smaller on scroll down, and so does it when I scroll up but with a HUGE delay. When I scroll up and I'm at scrollTop 0, it takes a couple of seconds before it resizes again. I figured it may be that it has to calculate all of the other scrollTop values before it gets to one that makes the header bigger again. How would I improve the code, so that it works without a delay?

Comment: The `scroll` even fires continously, what you need to do, is throttle the event, so it only fires once when going over the threshold, one way or the other etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @adeneo mentioned in comment .. you can use another if statement

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
      if($(document).scrollTop() > 300) {
        if($("#header").height() == 200){
          $("#header").animate({height: "50px"}, 400);
        }
      }
      else {
        if($("#header").height() == 50){
          $("#header").animate({height: "200px"}, 400);
        }
      }
      console.log($(document).scrollTop());
});
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/a7unbs2p/5/)